# How to update Expression in IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, odata, iqueryable

I have OData Web API + EF app and I need to modify some query in nested where. if a query looks like:

`SomeEntity?$filter=Name eq 'Y'&$Expand=Children($filter=Name eq 'x')`

It nests LINQ expression in a way that I can't just do 
IQueryable.Where(y => additional filter) which only applies to SomeEntity and not Children entity.

I have ExpressionVisitor that returns modified Expression for individual Where LINQ func but IQueryable.Expression is read-only and I am unable to overwrite this new to old Expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found that i can do
IQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery(my new expression)